# jQuery UI Datepicker in React throws Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, reactjs

When trying to get jQuery UI Datepicker working with React.js in a JSFiddle, the following error gets thrown in the console when you click on the input box:

> Uncaught TypeError: newDate.setHours is not a function

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/9ay9qdmd/

```
var Date = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <input type="text" className="datepicker" />;
    }
});

var Calendar = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    },
    render: function() {
        return ( 
            <form>
                <Date />
            </form>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Calendar />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've redefined a core JavaScript object: `Date`. If you rename it to something else, like `DateInput`, it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/0vd0wygu/).

```
var DateInput = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <input type="text" className="datepicker" />;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Stupid mistake. In my main project, when I put `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` in `componentDidMount`, it doesn't activate at all. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? But you should ideally use a `ref` with [findDomNode](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.finddomnode) on the specific element you want to activate from within that component's `componentDidMount`. If this jQuery UI component manipulates the DOM though, you'll end up with problems.

Comment: Thanks. Solved it by applying `$('.datepicker').datepicker()` to the `onFocus` event of the `input`. Worked a charm. Will try your method tho too.

Comment: (I'm not really sure what you solved, as the jsfiddle I included in my answer worked).

Comment: Yes, your solution worked in the JSFiddle. The JSFiddle was a very basic example of what I was using it for. In my real codebase, the target input element does not exist on initial render. The User has to click something for the input box to appear. So the event could not be bound to the element at render, and had to be bound later. Hence, using `onFocus` to trigger the binding at a time when the element exists.

Comment: `componentDidMount` should work. You should be able to do `$(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.datePicker)).datepicker()` assuming you added `ref='datePicker'` to the element. You'll also need to unwire it when the component unmounts or risk "leaking" elements on the page.

Comment: I got this to work as well. I suggest using `$(".datepicker").datepicker()` inside a `componentDidMount` inside the _DateInput_ component